# Como criar divs com Imagens especificas?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, jsp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a melhor maneira de criar divs com as imagens abaixo utilizando CSS? Gostaria que meu painel ficasse exatamente como a imagem que está de exemplo.

Criei duas classes par tentar inserir, mas a mesma deu problema e a imagem ficou cortada.

```css
.squareGray{
    background-color:#808080;
    color:white; 
    font-size:30px;
    background-image:url("../Images/caixa_cinza.png");
    background-size: cover;

}

.squareGreen{
    background-color:green;
    color:white; 
    font-size:30px;
    background-image:url("../Images/caixa_green.png");
    background-size: no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<c:if test="${realizadoSG < metaSG}">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="marca">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="meta metaFormat">META:
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${SG.rows[0].META}" type="currency"/>
      </div>
      <div class="rel squareGray">ACUMULADO <br><br>
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${realizadoSG}" type="currency" /><br>
        <h2>
          
          <c:out value="${SG.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%</h2>
        </br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </c:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente, eu faria da seguinte forma:

Utilizaria 3 divs, uma é o container com o background do mapa do Brasil e usaria outras duas internamente para adicionar as 2 outras imagens.

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

E, usaria CSS grid para trabalhar as divs internamente das imagens. Pelo meu ver, as divs estão com uma margem a direita e a esquerda (e não estão centralizadas em nenhum eixo)

```
.bg {
  padding-top: nPx; //valor em px da margem para cima
  padding-right: nPx; //valor em px da margem para a direita

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, max-content);
  gap: nPx; //distância entre as duas imgs
  .img {
     background-image:url("...");
     background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Se não é isso que você está querendo, peço que você reformule um pouco sua pergunta pois tive dificuldade de entender o que você quer fazer, onde você quer chegar e como está sua situação no momento (como está ficando na sua tela)